# React Express integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Trying to test React+Express and running into a problem with routing

express:

```
router.get('/testCall', function(req, res) {
    res.json([{id: 'test'}]);
})
```

react:

```
fetch('/testCall')
            .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.body);
            console.log('end test');
                res.json();
            })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
```

The res variable variable doesn't hold my testing string and the res.body variable contains "ReadableStream". The final res prints undefined. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with integrating your front and back ends, but with failing to return a value from the the first then function.  Nothing is being passed to be logged in the following then. Try

```
return res.json()
```

You might have gotten messed up when you started putting in the logging statements. This would have worked fine:

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. So I guess the logging returns undefined and my then statement tries to print that return value?